# Getting rid of the outside lines in Google Chart's pie chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've looked at Google Chart's Pie Chart documentation and I can't find any property to remove the lines being created when a slice is being hovered (or clicked). If it's not really configurable, are there alternative solutions to remove it?

[image]

Comment: No, there's really no way to remove the hover and selection bars. I'll file a bug.

Comment: @JeremyFaller, thanks for confirming it and filing a bug for it :)